# How do I calculate time difference between current time and set time in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, time

I'm trying to calculate and show the difference between current time and a user set time.

Here's how I calculate current time

```
currentTimeOutlet.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
```

Here's how I get the user to enter in the time they want

```
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    alarmTimeOutlet.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use to calculate the time difference

```
let time1 = currentTimeOutlet
    let time2 = alarmTimeOutlet

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mma"

    let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1)!
    let date2 = formatter.date(from: time2)!

    let elapsedTime = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
    let hours = floor(elapsedTime / 60 / 60)
    let minutes = floor((elapsedTime - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60)


    timeDiffOutlet.text = ("\(Int(hours)) hr and \(Int(minutes)) min")
```

And here is how I plan to show it

```
    @IBOutlet weak var timeDiffOutlet: UILabel!
```

However I keep getting the errors "Cannot convert value of type 'UILabel?' to expected argument type 'String'" at these specific lines

```
let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1)!
    let date2 = formatter.date(from: time2)!
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: `let time1 = currentTimeOutlet.text`

Comment: Still getting the same error Desdenova :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to convert an UILabel to a date, but you actually want to convert the text that's inside the UIlabel to a date.

Try changing:

```
let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1)!
let date2 = formatter.date(from: time2)!
```

To:

```
let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1.text!)
let date2 = formatter.date(from: time2.text!)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Pointblaster!

But I got 3 errors after adding the .text 

- Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'
- Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
- Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

Comment: I would recommend reading up on optionals in swift, a good read that will help you a lot in your future swift endeavors. But i will help you with this. Just add an exclamation point, "!", after the ".text". So it should look something like: let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1.text!). This will force unwrap the value, meaning that it will always be treated as if the object is valid and not nil.

Comment: I have changed my original answer to the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks so much Pointblaster! I read up and tweaked the code slightly to get it to work :) Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to add `.text` to `time1` and `time2` ? If I good read, `time1` and `time2` are label. To have their String, you should add `.text`.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help THIBAULT! But I got 3 errors after adding the .text - Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String' - Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil' - Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil' –

Comment: `guard let goodTime1 = time1.text else { return } 

guard let goodTime2 = time2.text else { return } 

let date1 = formatter.date(from: goodTime1)! 

let date2 = formatter.date(from: goodTime2)!`

I know that you can resolve this problem with guard.